# Qt define variable similar to -D

Tags: c++, qt, ldap

As is in title, I need to compile my Qt code with some library and need to define some variable. More specifically I'm working on support for ldap authentication.

In plain C++ I achieved it by following compile command

```
g++ -I/home/user/development/openldap/include -L/home/user/development/openldap/lib/ -DLDAP_DEPRECATED main.cpp -o ldap -lldap
```

Unfortunately, when I try to define this variable in .pro file like DEFINES += LDAP_DEPRECATED, then it cannot find any reference to ldap libraries.

Does anyone know, where it should be defined ?

Comment: define and `-D` are not used to resolve references. They are macro definitions for the preprocessor.

Comment: Yes, but how can I define preprocessor variable in QT ? I think that it is by adding DEFINES += LDAP_DEPRECATED into the .pro file. Is it true ?

Before I define this variable, it cannot find ldap_simple_bind_s which is deprecated. After adding this variable it cannot resolve any ldap_ function.

Comment: can you show the pro file (corresponding to your command above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run qmake after your changes? I am confident that `DEFINES += LDAP_DEPRECATED` will result in the compiler being called with `-DLDAP_DEPRECATED` once you rebuild after you saved the changes to your .pro file and clicked "Run qmake" from the build menu. You are using the right way to define preprocessor variables in a QMake project file.

However, for the other command line options it seems you are going to need these as well:

```
# LDAP Support
DEFINES += LDAP_DEPRECATED
INCLUDEPATH += /home/user/development/openldap/include
LIBS += -L/home/user/development/openldap/lib/ -lldap
```

By the way, the syntax for `LIBS` can be used on Windows as well, the `-L` argument will be translated into a library directory and the `-l` into a library filename.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I wanted to compile it in static way, so I was using this LIBDIR = -L$$SMON_ROOT/usr/lib/libldap.a. When I used shared, as you sugested it at least get compiled. How can I compile it in a static way ?

Comment: LIBS += -static -L/home/user/development/openldap/lib/ -lldap